# How to change the HADOOP log files location

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running a hadoop process, which take couple of hours and lots of space, and the process stops because there is not much space. The Hadoop `tmp` folder has huge space remaining so I think it is the problem with the `Hadoop_log_files` dir, as I've checked and there is not much space there. So could anyone please advise how to change the hadoop log file location to be in another location instead of `/home/hduser/hadoop/logs` without having to change the whole location of the hadoop setup. I'd be very thankful for any assistance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a property in the `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
# export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/logs
```

I changed it to `export newlocation/logs` and this solved the problem :)